# How to make the bot speak on another channel? (with discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am wanting my bot to send a message to a certain channel, (but I do not put the id because my bot will be public)
I used this command:

```
await client.send_message(destination=teste, content='oi (hello)')
```

But it does not result in anything and gives the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects\LennieBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "PycharmProjects/LennieBot/main.py", line 42, in on_message
    if message.content.lower().startswith((prefix) + 'botavatar'):
NameError: name 'teste' is not defined
```

Someone could help me (do not call the words in another language, I'm Portuguese c:)

Comment: And I took the paths from my user (c:users)

Comment: Can you verify if teste is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn’t define the variable ‘teste’. Assuming you want to send your message into a server channel, you have to get that channel first:

```
teste = client.get_channel(“id”)
```

where ‘id’ is the channel id you want to send your message in. Note that this must be a string, not an integer.